# How to show alert on browser back button click event using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show alert while clicking on the back button in the browser. it only works before clicking on the back button, when you click to somewhere else on the page, otherwise, it will go to the previous page without alert message.

I have added my code here. I want to go back when the page loads.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
        //window.history.pushState('', null, './');
        window.history.pushState(null, "", window.location.href);
        $(window).on('popstate', function() {
            alert('Warning! Your data will lose.');
            document.location.href = 'www.redirecturl.com';

        });
     }
    });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Disable Browser Back Button Using JavaScript</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js">
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="Page2.html">Click Here...</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using JQuery here

Comment: The back button is there for a reason. You can implement [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) to bring up something like a data loss popup. Disabling the back button breaks the common web experience for your site. That being said, you can push multiple hashchanges to the history and implement [`window.onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) to navigate forward when you get a hashchange event, which effectively disables the back button.

Comment: There really is no good way to detect if "back button" was clicked. You can use `onbeforeunload ` event, which fires if the user leaves the page. If you really only want the back button to be watched, take a look at this [article](http://www.webdevelopmenthelp.net/2013/12/browser-back-button-click-event.html). It maybe works, but I would not reccommend you to use it!

Comment: @TomMarienfeld your right it's not good blocking back button. but I have a situation which is, it's a form in ajax. input fields are shown on the page by page each input will be sent over ajax to the database. so if user wants to go back to the previous page(having input fileld) it will get an error. that's why i wanted to block the back button with alert message.

Comment: I have a situation which is, it's a form in ajax. input fields are shown on the page by page each input will be sent over ajax to the database. so if user wants to go back to the previous page(having input fileld) it will get an error. that's why i wanted to block the back button with alert message.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `onbeforeunload` event

**using jquery**

```js
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
  myFunction();
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});

function myFunction(){
     // Write your business logic here
     alert('Bye');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Close this window, press F5 or click on the link below to invoke the onbeforeunload event.</p>

<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Click here to go to w3schools.com</a>
```

**Using Javascript**

```js
window.onbeforeunload = s => "";
```

```html
<body>

<p>Close this window, press F5 or click on the link below to invoke the onbeforeunload event.</p>

<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Click here to go to w3schools.com</a>

</body>
```

Comment: It doesn't work when clicking on browser's back button

Answer (score 0):

Put It in your JS file and it will work .. when your press the browser back button it will alert you to leave or cancel.

```
 $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
            return '>>>>>Before You Go<<<<<<<< \n Your custom message go here';
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
  window.addEventListener("popstate", function (event) {
    $.confirm({
      boxWidth: "30%",
      title: "Alert",
      model: true,
      content: "The Changes made will be cleared",
      buttons: {
        Continue: function () {
          history.back();
        },
        Cancel: function () {
          history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
        },
      },
    });

  });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).